# How do I prevent kernel from updating beyond ATI GPU

Tags: upgrade, partial-upgrade

Current ATI driver can't handle kernels newer than, perhaps, 3.16x

What's the best way to prevent kernel upgrades from removing proprietary ATI driver?

Open driver is not an option, that kills 1/3 of GPU performance.

Comment: What ATI driver and card do you mean?

Comment: AMD A10-7800 APU   The official AMD/ATI graphics driver won't install, at all, on 15.04, not sure about earlier versions of the 'buntus.

Comment: I think it is still supported, and later there will be drivers for newer kernels. But now it is OK to use them with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: The open source driver will not only limit your GPU performance. AMD A-series are APU's, meaning they can change their clock speed on demand. This, however, requires the fglrx driver, else the CPU speed will stay at minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Kernels will not upgrade to another major version through routine update & upgrade process. So you need not do anything for that. If you have installed 3.16.0-X-X version, you will get only security updates and bug fixes, which will affect only  (X-X).